# when trying to capitalize the first letters, #1305 - FUNCTION DatabaseName.LEN does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to capitalize the first letters in a text column  and I use the following:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Column=UPPER(LEFT(Column,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(Column,2,LEN(Column)));
```

But I am getting this error

```
#1305 - FUNCTION Databasename.LEN does not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LEN` isn't a valid name for a builtin MySQL function.

If you want to use a function named `LEN`, you would need to create a function of that name.

MySQL does provides a builtin `CHAR_LENGTH` function. But you don't even need to use that.

The `SUBSTRING` function doesn't require a third argument. I think this would work for your purpose, just:

```
 SUBSTRING(Column,2)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Dear spencer7593 I took your suggestion and @gview 's suggestion both and made the following query which worked perfectly, UPDATE Table
SET Column=Concat(UPPER(LEFT(Column,1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(Column,2)));

Comment: @Schwann: If your question has been answered, you can "accept" an answer. And that will be one less "unanswered" question left hanging on StackOverflow.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @spencerr7593, the answer only changes the first word of each column and not the entire column will be corrected, that is the reason I did not mark it as answered

Comment: @Schwann: I read the question as asking "Why is MySQL returning this error (`#1305 - FUNCTION DatabaseName.LEN does not exist)`" when I run this SQL statement?"  And that's the question I attempted to answer. Given no example data and no demonstration of the expected result, I didn't read the question as asking "What SQL statement can I use to achieve this particular result?" (If that's the question that was being asked, I missed it.)

Answer (score 2):

As explained, your syntax is incorrect.  A working solution is this:

```
UPDATE Table SET Column = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(Column, 1)), SUBSTRING(Column, 2));
```

Your use of '+' will not work with MySQL, even if you fix the issue with LEN.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final working query which is a mix of what @spencer7593 and @gview suggested.

```
UPDATE Table SET Column=Concat(UPPER(LEFT(Column,1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(Column,2)));
```